# The [dark] side do not join. Lied they did about their cookies

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, retag-request

Tags I have found:

- [dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dark) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [darken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/darken) - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed)
- [light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light)

Suggest I do, we clean-up these tags. Burnination even. Experts there cannot exist. Usefulness they offer us not (missing are the the excerpt and wiki for all tags).

Reconnaissance results (total of all tags they are),

- 340 posts,
- 2% closed,
- 50% a score of <0 have.

---

In all seriousness, I'm suggesting we clean-up/re-tag (or even burninate) these tags, as [dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dark) & [darken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/darken) are rather generic and useless. Such posts can be retagged with more meaningful tags, even if that means creating new ones (e.g, [wix-dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wix-dark)/[dark-gdk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dark-gdk)) as others have suggested.

[light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light) *seems* to have a genuine use for: 3D rendering, openGL, 2D graphics etc, so maybe only a clean-up would be necessary (as the tag is being used for [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23754965/2246344) [purposes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22312681/2246344)). Some posts may need to be retagged with [light-sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light-sensor).

So, generally speaking,

- Most posts tagged with [dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dark) can be replaced with: [gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui)/[colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colours)/[themes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/themes),
- And most [darken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/darken)'ed posts can be replaced with: [gui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gui)/[colours](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/colours)/[fade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fade)/[background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/background).

For the few remaining posts, (as mentioned previously) we could simply create new tags. So, what does the Jedi Council have to say about the matter?

Comment: [tag:dark] seems [to be for dark gdk](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22DarkGDK%22), which is a .net and C++ library. It should be renamed to [dark-gdk]

Comment: @InfiniteRecursion Hmm, but as slugster pointed out, the tag also seems to be for the Wix toolset...

Comment: Yes, [dark] should be replaced with specific tags like [wix-dark] and [dark-gdk] @Sam

Comment: But... I'm an expert in the field of the `darken` image processor: it changes every pixel to black D:

Comment: @mypal125 I do it to both computers and humans... D:

Comment: Are you sure they lied about the cookies?

Comment: @PaulDraper Well, it's your choice if you want join them or not ([and find out for yourself](http://cdn.slowrobot.com/4172014062343.jpg)). Just remember [we have cookies too](http://fc03.deviantart.net/fs37/f/2008/280/e/8/The_Light_Side_by_ParanoidMetroid.jpg).

Comment: I predict soon someone coming and posting something similar for [tag:background] [tag:colours]

Comment: What's the right tag for ambient light sensors?

Comment: @BenVoigt "light sensors" of what sort?

Comment: @Sam: [Ambient light sensors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn613947%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) are those things [mobile devices have](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Sensor.html#STRING_TYPE_LIGHT) to discover whether they're in a dark room/well-lit room/sunlight and adjust the screen accordingly (among other interesting things to do with the data).

Comment: @BenVoigt Ah right. Well I guess it would be the [light-sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light-sensor) tag.

Comment: You might add that to the question since it's likely some questions tagged [tag:light] will need to be retagged to [tag:light-sensor]

Answer (score 27):

You mention graphics/rendering/OpenGL as a possible legitimate use of [light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light). A more specific tag for that use is [lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting). So if [light](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/light) is used for that purpose, I would suggest to retag with [lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting).

To add to it, there's also [lights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lights), which has no description, but seems to be used almost exclusively in the graphics domain. My proposal would be to declare it a synonym of [lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting). Or to get rid of it, and re-tag the current uses with [lighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lighting).

"Lighting" is a widely used term in the graphics domain, and I'm not aware of any other common uses. Well, maybe in interior decorating, but that's not really on topic for SO. So it seems like a specific enough tag name, and it already has a description that matches that use.

Comment: How about [tag:shadow] to be either a synonym for this, or linked to it? Similar in spirit, and should take care of the [tag:dark].

Comment: Rendering shadows is not the same as lighting. Lighting is much more general. Shadows can be a part of lighting calculations, but lighting is often done without considering shadows.

Answer (score -30):

No, you should not burninate the tags.

Clean them up yes you may. But burninate must you not.

### Why?

Because Light and Dark are two of the tools that are part of the [Wix toolset](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/overview/alltools.html). Of course that still leaves [darken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/darken) (AFAIK there is no tool or product called that, but y'know I could be wrong on that one).

This is a regular occurrence where legitimate tags get misused for other things. The right thing to do here is to retag where necessary.

To be honest I don't think replacing the tag on non-Wix posts would be appropriate either as they can be the name or description of a process for which there are established methods or algorithms. Gui/colors/themes are not really good replacement tags for [dark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dark) or [darken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/darken).

Comment: Of the 52 questions tagged `dark`, only 2 seem to be about Wix. From a quick scan of the active questions, the tag is mostly used to indicate something is or should be in a dark color, mostly UI-themes, color schemes etc. IMO the tag should burn and be blacklisted; if a tag for Wix dark is required, it should be called `wix-dark` and not `dark`.

Comment: Lol, the [newest one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17207185/2246344) was posted a year ago (the [other one](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5276144/2246344) was 3 years ago). And both have a score of 0. Not sure if it's even worth creating a `[wix-dark]` tag...